# Custom hotkey for selecting edit field

Tags: interface

I saw a video with a useful tip, but can't find it again. The author defined a custom key to focus on the three transform vertex coordinates; x, y, and z. This is different from creating hotkeys to perform a function such as "subdivide" (RMB, select "create shortcut") as that doesn't work for me. The fields turned green and when pressed, the edit field was focused and the value was selected so he could instantly overwrite the value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that they actually setup a shortcut to edit the values. A background colour of green indicates that the values are keyframed but not on the current frame, while a yellow background indicates a keyframe exists on the current frame.

See below, the location is keyframed on the current frame while rotation has a keyframe on another frame.

[image]

When the mouse is over the values pressing <kbd>I</kbd> will insert a keyframe for the values at the current frame. You can also right click and choose Insert Keyframes, you also have options to Delete (only current frame) or Clear (all frames)  Keyframes.

Clicking in the centre of a number field will enter edit mode allowing you to type in the value to use.

Comment: That's how the UI looked, so you're probably correct about the keyframe bit. I do remember the fields just getting focus without the mouse cursor being over them, so somehow he did it, but it seems it didn't have anything to do with the color.

Comment: This thread http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1273/how-to-input-location-of-selected-vertex-using-keyboard-only describes a patch solving the current issue I have. It lets you perform simple arithmetic during transitions. Does anyone know if there is an addon that does this?

Comment: @RobbieGee That patch is now a part of blender, you can use it in 2.70. You can keyframe all location (or rotation etc.) channels at once by pressing `I` in the 3D view.