# Dimensions panel: how to proportionaly get all 3 dimensions entering just one

Tags: dimensions

Is there a way to proportionaly scale an object entering a specific value in only one of the 3 dimensions? Basically I need to "link" the 3 values inside "Dimensions" so if I enter a specific value in 1 the others are automatically calculated.

Exemple: I have an object with these dimesions

[image]

I want to enter 2,5m as Y value and to automatically obtain the proportional X and Z value.
How can I do that? It's a very basic function but I can't find it.

---

I discovered that what I'm looking for is exactly the "Link Scale" function which was present in Transform Panel until version 2:48

[image]

I think is insane to remove a function like this. It's unbelievable ...
So.. I really thank those who are suggesting more engineering procedures but I'm looking for something easier as "Scale Link" was.
**Really..  there must be a way, an addon or maybe a secret shortcut to simply link the three dimensions in the Transform Panel**

Comment: Why dont you use S button to scale?

Comment: Because it's not what I need. I need to manualy insert 1 value and automatically get the other... What value do you enter after S button to obtain Y= 2,5 ................?

Comment: **The best solution I've found is the Link Scale script in this forum page:** https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?330451-Link-Scale-script-Please-help-me-with-my-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the other answer explained the (simple) math, nobody mentioned that you can simply input the two numbers during the scale operation.

1. Hover over the **Dimension** property you want change. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the current value to clipboard.
2. In the 3D view press <kbd>S</kbd> to enter the scale operation. Now type the number you want to scale the dimension to, then type `/` (division) and then press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied value.
   <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> confirm click or press enter.

The current scale input is display in the menu bar.

I demonstrate this by scaling the X and Y dimension to 2.

[image]

Remember to enter number with a fullstop not a comma.

Don't: <s>5.000,5</s>

Do:    **5000.5**

Comment: I think your suggestion is helpful but uncomfortable almost as much as that of WKG. In addition, after I press S, if I need for example to enter 5/3 - Blender writes the "/" before the "5" and I get a nonsense [1/(5|)]. If I add the "3" it write [1/(53|)]. The correct one wold be [5/3|] but i impossible to write...
All this makes me even more tired of Blender ..
I also discovered that after 2:49 version Blender has removed the "Link Scale" function from Transform Panel that is exactly what I need. It's unbelievable...

Comment: WKG suggests me to enter = after / and now I'm able to use your method. Thanks to you and thanks to WKG. This is not the solution I was looking for but at least it works. I hope this feature will return in the Blender because it is ridiculous to have it removed.
At least I hope someone will create an addon for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's where still the Scale operation should be used. The question is how to obtain right factor for scaling.
The brute force method is to calculate how many times is 2.5 less than 3.356:

3.356 / 2.5 = 1.342

So you want the object to become 1.342 times smaller.
Press <kbd>S</kbd> for Scale operation. But if entering 1.342 right now, it will scale 1.342 times bigger, not smaller.

So the only step is to invert this. In order to avoid any 3-rd party calculations, after pressing <kbd>S</kbd> enter "=" sign (no quotes) which will make Blender to treat further text as formula and then 1 / 1.342. The final formula:

Press <kbd>S</kbd>, then = 1 / 1.342.

This method is brute force at least because final Y dimension would be 2.501 (with mentioned values). This should have to do with floating point precision.

Comment: Are you telling me that I need do separately use a calculator to manually obtain a right scale factor when I simply need to enter a dimension value and change the others 2 proportionaly to that? ...... I'm shocked. I rellay do not want to seem ungrateful or unkind, I swear, but sorry it can not be true. Blender can not have a similar lack.

Comment: @frenksisco Blender doesn't have lack here (depends on what to understand under a lack though). Answer by Leander alredy pointed out a way to skip any calculations by just copy/paste. But you aren't limited to that - you can setup a [driver](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/index.html) for Measurement panel to make values change when one is changed. Besides the time for actual setup and for maybe learning drivers, it will be absolutely unefficient to solve it in this way, creating self-changing setup for only one time of changing instead of using simple math.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is a great software, maybe the most advanced free opensources software ever. But telling me to write a script, or to use the driver panel, or to use copy, paste and calculations to obtain a basic operation like this ... Is a lack. Yes a great lack.
In this case, any procedure more complicated than simply turning on a "link dimensions" function and enter one single value is a lack.
Moreover, as I said to Leander, although so far it seems the easiest way, I can not make his method work.

Comment: @frenksisco if you tried to follow instructions from my answer in Blender you would be able to do ones by Leander - *before entering 5/3 enter = sign* so it becomes `= 5 / 3`. Consider absence of poossibility to comfortably enter one value and automatically change others as a lack or whatever you like. It looks like [entering absolute values](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19503/is-there-a-way-to-enter-the-absolute-not-relative-value-of-a-transformation) is related. If you are *sure* it could be that useful provide a feature request or write addon yourself.

Comment: Your clarification to Leander method works. Thank you!
I repeat it is not the solution I was looking for but at least it works.
I think it's funny to request as a new feature an old one.. But yes I think this is the time. Where can I make a request for a Blender feature? Is there an official place?

Comment: @frenksisco http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests

Answer (score 1):

I understand frenksisco's frustration, and after 5 years there is still no ideal solution...
Thanks to the add-on Proportional Dimensions To New Size, the problem of proportional scaling (with mm or inch) of one object has been solved.

Now, problem is when we want to resize multiple selected objects to an exact dimension (mm, inch) without having to merge them.

So far I have found that with the help of “Proportional Dimensions To New Size” add-on I can achieve that simple task with a lot of extra work…

For example, we have two objects that we want to enlarge proportionally by setting the desired height.

- select the objects that we want to enlarge proportionally
- OBJECT > SNAP > CURSOR TO SELECTED
- OBJECT > SET ORIGIN > ORIGIN TO 3D CURSOR
- OBJECT > DUPLICATE OBJECTS
- move the duplicated objects aside
- merge duplicated objects, OBJECT > JOIN
- we select the original objects and the duplicated object, for the active object we mark the duplicated
- in field Z at “Proportional Dimensions” panel type the desired height

We got our two objects proportionally enlarged to the desired height, we can now delete the duplicated.

[image: Video description of commands]

Does anyone know of an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Denis was on the right track, but you may need a little more information.  Let's say you want to scale Y by 2.5.  If you want the other dimensions to scale proportionately, then they should also be scaled by 2.5.  So, with the object selected in Object mode, just press [S] [2] [.] [5] [Enter].  That's it!

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I think both of you have not understood.
I do not want to scale Y "by" 2.5 factor...... I want Y to become 2.5m, not times, I want to set a specif dimension in Y - dimensions - not scale factor! - And to automatically and proportionaly obtain the other dimensions ... I really do not now how to better explain the thing .... I can guarantee that in all other 3D modelling software is a very basic feature

Comment: I changed the question title to make it less confusing