# How to scale dimensions proportionally to a specific size?

Tags: transforms, scale, dimensions

I modeled a man and would like to scale him down to be exactly 6' tall (Z dimension), however I cannot find a way to do that. I know I can go to front ortho view and and use the normal scale <kbd>S</kbd>  key to scale it, however that requires some pretty specific fine tuning in order to get it to the right dimensions.

I'd like to be able to essentially type "6" into the Z dimension (don't worry I have it setup in imperial) and have it scale the X and Y dimensions proportionally.

Comment: Deleted my question beceuse it's not what you asked i think, this might help though: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72810/dimensions-panel-how-to-proportionaly-get-all-3-dimensions-entering-just-one

Comment: Here's another scenario that might be useful [How to resize an object proportionally via setting edge length?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282919/142292)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As far as I know it can't easily be done on a single atomic operation unfortunately, but I generally use the following workflow.

To scale uniformly with precise absolute dimensions, in the *Properties Area* of the *3D View* just type in the exact absolute dimension you require in the single desired axis.

Now check the resulting scaling on that axis, Blender will have calculated the appropriate factor for that vector. You can now copy-paste the value with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to the other axis so they all remain uniform. No need to click on the field to edit, hovering the value and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is enough.

Apply the scale afterwards if you desire with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>  *Apply > Scale* while in *Object Mode*.

[image]

Make sure your object has uniform scaling on all axis before using this technique, otherwise you may get unexpected results. Apply scale before proceeding with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Scale*

Comment: Simple **and** accurate

Comment: You'd think there'd just be a button you could click to lock the proportions or something similar, but this looks as good as it can get. Thank you!!~

Comment: Once you scale to the right size remember to Apply Size (Ctrl+A)...

Comment: edit mode, and in version 2.79 does this also work?

Comment: This only ever worked in *Object Mode*

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a new Blender feature, but [Numeric Input](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/numeric_input.html#) is available directly as well.

Excerpt:

> Using the mouse for transformations is convenient, but if you require more precise control, you can also enter numeric values. After pressing the shortcut type a number to indicate the magnitude of the transformation. Then confirm or cancel. E.g. pressing <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd> will double the scale of an object.
>
> Move G
> By default and with no other key presses, the translation will occur along the X axis.
>
> Rotation R
> The rotation is in clockwise direction for positive values.
>
> Scale S
> Scaling works in almost identical fashion to translation. The primary difference is that by default, scaling applies equally to all three axes.
>
> You can see the numbers you enter in the 3D Viewport footer.

Comment: I was even able to lock z axis with and scale 120%. All I did was  press "S" followed by  "1.2" followed by "Shift +z"

Answer (score 2):

[image: Scale]

If you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while scaling, you can fine tune without too much trouble...

Comment: Once you scale to the right size remember to **Apply Size** (Ctrl+A)

Comment: But with this way won't provide scaling factor with a way to "have it scale the X and Y dimensions proportionally"

Comment: This requires eyeballing values and is not totally precise.

Comment: @Duarte - Glad to learn from your answers but also curious - what is not totally precise about 0.600?

Comment: If you enter 6.0 Blender will try to match 6.0 as best as possible for the situation. If you approximate it by dragging the cursor until a value shows up in the box, it may very well be 6.002 or 5.995, and you have little control over it. In most cases it probably won't matter much, but if you are looking for numerical precision there are better ways