# Is there a way to set specific dimensions in inches or an other measurment?

Tags: 3d-printing

I have imported a model and the size of the hole of a cylinder is too big and I'm wanting to scale it to 2in. across. Is there any way that I can set the scale down to that measurement without having to move my mouse up and down to get the correct measurement?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimesions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size

Answer (score 2):

I expect the easiest way is to use the [measuere it addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Measureit). This is included with blender so you just have to enable it.

In edit mode, select two vertices on opposite sides of the hole. Add a measure segment. Scale the mesh until the measurement shows the size you want, holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while scaling will allow for more precise adjustments. You will want to make sure the objects scale is 1.0 to get correct measurements. After you have resized the object, you can delete the measurement.

[image: MeasureIt tools panel]

[image: measure in use]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can find in the image below.

Scene>>units.

[image]