# Real world scale size?

Tags: modeling, mesh, scale, units

I am working on a project that's a bathroom, it's supposed to fit real world scale, the size of the bathroom should be 2,50х1,5 and the height 2,2. How am I supposed to use these numbers in Blender in order to get the size right?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size/87250#87250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a cube, enable the measurement overlay so that you can see the dimensions of the object.

[image]

Scale the object to the size you need.

Comment: Yup, this helped me understand how to do proper measure, thanks all for your comments, you were very useful! :)

Comment: The "Measurement Overlay" is only accessible when in the "Modelling" mode in Blender.

Comment: In "Edit Mode" in "Layout" tab I see the measurement overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I the toolbar on the right, click on the Scene Property tab (the fifth from the top), open the tab Units, then select the units you want (Metric or imperial), then in Length choose the base unit (Meters, Centimeters, Inches, Feet...).

To get the size of the room right, you could sketch it with a few cubes/planes. Add a Cube/Plane, then press N to open the Item menu on the right, set the dimension in there.