# Exact Measurements - or resize to specific dimension

Tags: scale, measurement

I’m pretty new to blender and started with sketchup. I find overall that it is much more powerful software that is generally not as buggy - and can be used for many more things.

Still, I struggle with one tool in particular, the measure tool. When I want to measure from a vertex to vertex, I turn on snapping and can use the ctrl key to snap to the second vertex but for some reason I can’t do that with the first one. And so I zoom in very far to click on the first point then go all the way across the the other point. It is always wrong - really. So I zoom in even further to the first point and I see that it didn’t snap to this point. I mean, with ALL of the amazing capacities of blender this definitely surprises me.

I’m not expecting the great features of the measure from sketchup like resize the model by measuring a distance and rescaling it to that size - such as for a doorway or table height or other known quality, nor for the easy snap to x y or z direction. But am I missing something - is there a good snappable add-on I don’t know about?

I realize that blender is not a cad software, but I hope you understand that the measure tool seems super underdeveloped given the other aspects of blender that are now so sophisticated.
Thanks for any clarity!

Comment: if you click and drag with measure tool, a line will be create and you can select one end of this line and snap it to a vertex. Then select the another end  and snap it to another vertex. But, from what I understand, you say that this snap dont work in boths ends of the measure line? can you show me more details? gif or video to show what is happening? see this: [gif](https://devtalk.blender.org/uploads/default/original/2X/4/43b9dfa08db21876dd4bfde9effbe44165229f9f.gif)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size/87250

Answer (score 4):

First point can't currently be snapped from the start.

It is a [known limitation that is currently being looked](https://developer.blender.org/D7000) at, it is part of a broader limitation that includes among other things [not being able to set a base point for moving](https://developer.blender.org/T66484) before transforming

Current recommended workaround is to eyeball the first point, precisely snap the second one, then return to the first one and move it while using snapping.

[image]

### Edit

As of commit [Gizmo Library: New Snap Gizmo](https://developer.blender.org/rB2e73e1390e3a87d16fc4016d629253c1228af255) from 27 May 2020, there is now a new generic special type of gizmo whose purpose among other things is providing snapping before use for various tools and operators in Blender, like [base point snapping for transforms such as move or rotate](https://developer.blender.org/T66424), or [snapping the first measure point of a ruler](https://developer.blender.org/D7071) without having to backtrack

Comment: Ok!  Thank you.  And this helps me significantly but does seem like a workaround too.  I just didn't think that it could be possible that snap with ctrl was possible without the first vertex being an option.  I also would like to suggest that they implement a rescale by measurement feature such as sketchup has.  In this case if you measure a distance such as the 2m cube above, that shows in the data entry box at the bottom but you can instead make it any measurement - 1km or 1cm or anything.  Very useful to resize the model or part.

Comment: @Hector You can suggest new functionality here https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I wonder if you have duplicate vertices?  Blender may be trying to snap to a different vertex than you want.

Try this...

In edit mode, select all (A).  Then Merge vertices (Mesh>Merge>By Distance).

Watch the Status Bar at the bottom of the screen.  It'll say "Removed x vertices".

This is very common until you get a feel for proper topology creation, and it's a function you'll want to be familiar with.