# How do I resize a plane in blender

Tags: transforms

I am trying to resize a plane in blender to match the size of my yard. (Doing this to plan where to put a shed)

I am a total noob to blender and it took me an hour to figure this out so I wanted to make sure it was documented how to do this process.

Comment: it might be a good idea to watch some free beginner tutorials for Blender because especially for beginners it is not intuitive. But i am sure your question was answered here before....e.g. here : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and created a plane. Selected the object and pressed the `N` key and that pulled up in the GUI the ability for me to resize my plane to the specific dimensions of my yard.