# How to resize an object proportionally via setting edge length?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, objects, transforms

I'm trying to scale or resize an object to a specific size by picking an edge from that mesh, and then setting that edge to a new measurement, automatically resizing the whole object proportionally. In other poly-based 3d software that I use, it is really easy to do. The tool is called 'tape measure' tool which has the option to resize). How to do that in Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size

Comment: How to scale an object by selecting a reference linear distance (from point A to point B), and then simply typing the desired new number distance we want. Is that possible?

Comment: maybe the Archimesh or Archicad addons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale dimensions proportionally to a specific size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size)

Comment: I found something similar but not exactly what I was looking for, I'm talking about 'CAD Transform' addon for blender, which can do the job, but in my opinion it is a little bit tricky, and not as simple as 'tape measure tool' from the other software that I use. Thanks people, I appreciate all your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and tick *Edge Length* under *Overlays* so you can see the length of any selected edge. You can set the length of the selected edge using `bpy.ops.object.mesh_edge_length_set()`.

[image]

You can easily resize the entire mesh proportionally after resizing the selected edge using the following script. Simply select an edge and go to [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html) under the *Scripting Tab*. Then input the new length value for the `set_my_selected_edge_to_length` variable in the script and click *Run Script*.

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh

set_my_selected_edge_to_length = 1.43 #your new length for selected edge

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

def resize(scale):
    ob.scale = (scale, scale, scale)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)

for e in bm.edges:
    if not e.select:
        continue
    scale = set_my_selected_edge_to_length / e.calc_length()
    resize(scale)
    break

bm.free()
```

The [`Edit Mesh Tools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/edit_mesh_tools.html) has also pretty useful functions that also include edge resizing. I recommend installing this addon under menu *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Edit Mesh Tools*

[image]

The tools are available under *Edit Tab > Mesh Tools*.

[image]

Comment: Oops .. sorry about the side-effects ... :)