# Scale group of objects to size

Tags: transforms, object-mode, dimensions

I'd like to scale up a few text objects to a certain total X dimension, keeping aspect.
Selecting all allows scaling as group, but this only affects scale factor and as such does not allow an exact dimension.
Setting the X dimension for a selection only affects the active object (I was hoping to get the scale factor to use on the group's other axes).

The scale factor obtained by converting to a joined mesh and then adjusting dimension seems off by about half.

See [How to scale dimensions proportionally to a specific size?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size) for sizing a single object.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is hold `Alt` while changing the scale like in that other post.

Holding `Alt` allows you to change the same value for multiple objects at the same time.

[image]