# Unable to export skin texture in .Alembic format

Tags: texturing, export, alembic

I exported Rigged avatar from blender(3.2) in .Alembic format as shown below

[image]

and exported the same into Marvelous Designer but could not import skin textures into Marvelous Designer.

[image]

How can I get skin textures exported from Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos can export the avatar with specific height/width in mm. is this possible

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87243/how-to-scale-dimensions-proportionally-to-a-specific-size

Comment: Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos for the link... i tried with your approach for setting the avatar height to 1800 mm its not working and regarding external skin textures exporting in alembic format is still a challenge could not get a solution. Seems to be challenge will figure it out