# IIf I loaded an stl file and the scale should have been 1:32 scale, ( 647.7mm), and it was 20,726mm, (full scale), then file was not scaled to 1:32?

Tags: transforms

I am a newbie. I bought this file and paid an extra 50.00 to have it scaled to 1:32 scale of the full size locomotive.  I open the file in Blender and the loco was full scale.  If he scaled it to 1:32 scale, shouldn't the file have been the 1:32 scaled size?, which would have been 647.7mm not 20726mm.  I don't know about .stl files as I thought it could have showed up as full scale and yet still be scaled to 1:32. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, rbrown, welcome to BSE. You really shouldn't need to pay anyone to scale a model.. it's a simple operation. Check out 'scale to dimension' answers.. for example (this one)[https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/87250/35559]. If  you're still having trouble, please do go ahead and ask about the specific trouble you're having.  I think it's fair to call this version  a duplicate of quite a few similar questions in the archive.